# How to access a file outside AppBundle?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We are working with Forge's Design Automation API for Revit and we have an AppBundle prepared. However, currently we have a JSON file inside the AppBundle, which we can access and read, but we would like to have this JSON file stored somewhere else where we can update it without updating the AppBundle every time. (this JSON file will be updated pretty frequently)

Obviously the AppBundle needs an access to that JSON file for our project to work, so we started exploring the possibilities. In the [Restriction](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/#design-automation-api-for-revit) documentation, it states that "No network access is allowed", but in the Revit part it says "Access to cloud paths is restricted" which indicates that there is some accessibility to the cloud?

Could we use the cloud to store only the JSON file, and could the AppBundle read that file? OR is there any other (better?) solution for our specific need? The goal is to have the AppBundle uploaded once, and then we should only update the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possiblity to send and recieve HTTP requests from your appbundle code, However, Open Network feature is still under development,
there still might be some changes related to this feature before
it's officially released, please wait for our official announcement
and we will share all the details and the demo source code when
it's announced released.

Please contact forge.help@autodesk.com to require allow-list to
try this new feature.

Please send the details of Engine, Forge App Client Id and the [nickname of the app.](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step3-create-nickname/)

The protocols supported: Only HTTP/HTTPS calls are allowed,
no other protocols are supported.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/open-network-preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will contact via email soon. However, I have one question regarding AppBundle update (just for some additional info): Our AppBundle has 10 .rfa files inside, if we have an AppBundle uploaded and if we just change the JSON file and we want to update the AppBundle, will it upload the whole AppBundle again (with all the .rfa files) or just the changed file? (git-like?) I'm asking this because of the upload time.

Comment: Is JSON file part of appbundle ?, or JSON file is sent through your workitem request, if you are not editing appbundle contents, you don't need to have reupload the appbundle again.  What I do is I fetch the appbundle from the DA server compute the hashes if I find the difference in hashes between local appbundle and appbundle on server, then only I reupload.

Comment: @codeFreak24, I think you can just provide this JSON file as one of inputs of the WorkItems. If its payload is small, just send its content as data URI in WorkItem payload; otherwise, send its URL in WorkItem payload. The appbundle can access the json file.

Comment: @EmmaZhu the JSON file is around 15 kB max. Is it possible to send it that way? And what is the limitation of sending with WorkItems?

Comment: @codeFreak24, we have a limit on WorkItem payload size, which is 16KB. For the JSON file around 15KB, you can upload the JSON file to a Cloud Storage and send the signed url to the file as the argument URL of one of the inputs of WorkItem. You can give a "localName" for this input, so the JSON file will be downloaded as this "localName", then your AppBundle can access it.

Comment: @EmmaZhu I understand, thank you!
Can I get you to send me an example how the payload should look like in both cases (if the payload is small and if it's not)

Comment: Oh, and how to read/access that file from WorkItem Payload inside AppBundle code?

Comment: @codeFreak24, do you still need help? I saw you already post other questions related. If you still need help, you can send email to forge.help@autodesk.com directly.

Comment: @codeFreak24, you can just provide (big size)JSON file as one of input and access it in the appbundle's code in the SAME way as you do for the revit model as an input.

Answer (score 0):

'Cloud paths' possibly refers to RVT models stored in BIM360. Afaik, no network access is allowed, period. Hence, I am afraid the easiest way forward for you right now is to update the app bundle with the modified JSON every time you run it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
I guess that this means we can't use Forge's Document Management API either inside AppBundle at runtime. 
One question regarding the AppBundle update. Our AppBundle has 10 .rfa files inside, if we have an AppBundle uploaded and if we just change the JSON file and we want to update the AppBundle, will it upload the whole AppBundle again (with all the .rfa files) or just the changed file? (git-like?) I'm asking this because of the upload time.

Answer (score 0):

Another, related, discussion just came up which may also be of use:

Question: What's the maximum number of inputs that a design automation job can have? Would thousands (or tens of thousands) be possible?

Answer: There is no such a limit for the number of inputs. There is a limit on the work item’s JSON payload, which is 16KB. If the workitem needs thousands of inputs, probably you can zip them into a few inputs and use Design Automation to unzip them after.